# Closing QuickTime by Applescript

Tags: applescript, quicktime

I am trying to play a movie fullscreen one time, then close the player programmably.
I have tried using QTMovieView, command line and AppleScript and found the Applescript is the most simple way.

BUT, as I really don't know Applescript, I can not make the QuickTime auto close after movie playing.

Everything works fine but the "done" was unrecognized in the repeat line.
Here is the script with this error:

error "QuickTime Player got an error: Can't make done of document 1 into type specifier." number -1700 from done of document 1 to specifier

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
  activate
  open "/Users/...real path of the movie.mov"
  present document 1
  play document 1

  repeat until (get done of document 1)
  end repeat

  delay 2
  close document 1
end tell
```

Finally, I changed to this, is this ok?

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    quit
end tell
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    open "/Users/.../...mov"
    tell document 1
        present
        play
        repeat until playing is false
        end repeat
        delay 2
        close
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

New problem: app hang before video finish.

Comment: You don't need to quit the app before you relaunch it. You also don't need to close document 1 before you quit. Try my edited version.

Comment: may I move the delay 1 from middle to after end repeat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, however it doesn't seem very robust. Is it *guaranteed* that the `current time` will always end up being equal to the `duration`, given that they're both reals? You may want to put some "within epsilon" logic into the `repeat` condition.

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    play document 1
    repeat until (current time of document 1 = duration of document 1)

    end repeat
    delay 2
    close document 1
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you Graham, it works! but the QuickTime Player did not quit after playing. shall I use close?

Comment: Just change 'close document 1' to 'quit'. I didn't realise from the question you wanted to quit the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    tell document 1
        present
        play
        repeat until playing is false
            delay 1
        end repeat
    end tell
quit
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you adayzdone, it works too! but the QuickTime Player did not quit after playing. shall I use close?

Comment: If someone pauses the video, do you want the app to quit?