# Can AppleScript initiate Quicktime playback over the a local network?

Tags: applescript, quicktime

I've searched for a similar question but didn't find anything relevant. This question  [Closing QuickTime by Applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728854/closing-quicktime-by-applescript) is somewhat similar but doesn't address the network aspect of my question.

Specifically I would like to be able to press a "Play" button on one Mac and have Quicktime player(or similar app) start playback of a video-file simultaneously on one or more other computers on the LAN. The video files on the other computers are not necessarily identical to one another.

Latency could be an issue but I think that in situ testing could accommodate that well enough for my purposes.

More fundamentally, it doesn't have to be AppleScript/Quicktime Player. An off-the-shelf app written specially for this purpose would also be acceptable - better, maybe.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not near a pair of networked Macs right now, but I *think* something like this should work:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player" of machine "eppc://username@0.1.2.3.4"
    open "path/to/file.mov"
    play
end tell
```

You almost certainly need admin access to the remote machine, and to set it up to accept remote apple events (System Preferences->Sharing)